# how bash word wrap with \ works?

Tags: bash

In bash scripts why these lines work:

```
perl -e "...\
..."
```

but these don't:

```
perl -e \
"... \
..."
```

??

Comment: The backslash is not needed inside a quoted expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me.  The only thing i can suggest is, make sure there's nothing between the backslash and the newline.  (Any other whitespace could mess things up.)

Comment: lousy space! you're right, thanks. also i've known it's possible to replace " to ' and remove \

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is nothing between the contents of the string and the backslash if spaces are significant (see the second line of your second example).